# Highlighting menu/submenu in accordance with the rendered view

Tags: menu, backbone.js, menubar

I have a fairly large Backbone app with Menu/Submenu being a separate view. Inside the menu view i have the logic to handle click event on `li` and highlight that. However i am stuck on how to highlight a particular `li` when i navigate to another view from within the application (using the router, for eg.)

Options available:

1. From each of the Views `render()`, access the menu div and highlight the required `li`
2. Use Event mechanism and from each of the views `render()` trigger an event like `'CustomerUpdate::render'`.

I feel 2] is the right way to do it. But i am open to suggestions.

What techniques do you follow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**(1)** is a bit nasty, that leaks the menu's internal state and structure all over the place. You'll end up with your main views tightly coupled with your menu, that leads to a small ball of mud and small balls of mud always grow into big balls of mud.

I think **(2)** is on the right track but I'd pull it apart a little more. The current view is part of your application's state and switching views through a router is a change in your application's state. What do we use in Backbone to track state and state changes? We use models and `"change"` events. If you have a dedicated global model for your application's state:

```
AppState  = Backbone.Model.extend({});
app_state = new AppState;
```

Then the view that manages the menu could bind to changes in `app_state`:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'change_current_view');
    app_state.on('change:current_view', this.change_current_view);
}
```

and the event handler could deal with the `<li>`s:

```
change_current_view: function() {
    this.$('li').removeClass('current');
    // This selector is, of course, just for illustration
    this.$('#' + app_state.get('current_view')).addClass('current');
}
```

Then your router can swap the view and `app_state.set({ current_view: '...'})` to trigger the auxiliary actions. You could even have something, such as an application level view, that listens for `"change:current_view"` and let that listener deal with swapping the view; that would simplify your router. Here's a quick demo to help illustrate what I'm talking about:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/fr8sG/

This "application state model" approach is quite useful in general; you can easily add more bits of state to the app-model, set up preferences editors, etc. You'll also get persistence and application initialization almost for free.